# Android Manifest merger failed after sdk update?

Tags: android

this error randomly started happening today

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:6:5-20:19 to override.
```

so I did what is said to  and now this happens

```
Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

what gives?

Comment: check manifest.xml file for any error, if you have deleted any activity but its declaration is still there. And try cleaning the project.

Comment: Also update the libraries in build.gradel module with same version. e.g. 28.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because the same attribute has a different value in different lib.

Add `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory` in Application tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`
it will resolve this error.